# Javasript check current datetime with loop 2 between datetimes

Tags: javascript, flipclock

I'm working with time loop.

```
var startShow = [];
var endShow = [];

for(var i = 0; i < jsonStr[4].length; i < i++)
{
    startShow[i] = moment(jsonStr[4][i].start_show).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    //ex: 01/12/2021 18:32:40,01/12/2021 17:32:40,01/12/2021 16:52:40,01/12/2021 18:10:40
    endShow[i] = moment(jsonStr[4][i].end_show).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    //ex: 01/12/2021 18:53:55,01/12/2021 18:23:40,01/12/2021 19:32:40,01/12/2021 19:50:40
}
```

Now I have this FlipClock plugin,

```
var theCounters = $('.clock .value').FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
    callbacks:
    {
        interval:function()
        {
            var time = this.factory.getTime().time;
                            
            var currentTime = (moment(time).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                            
            //Here I need the currentTime check if there is a time between startShow and endShow matched.
            if(matched)
            {
                alert("matched");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("not matched");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My question, is it possible to check if there is a currentTime between startShow and endShow match with my above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two arrays for `startShow` and `endShow`, take one array as `showTime` and add object with `startShow` and `endShow` value. Also do not format time as it will convert value to string. Instead left it as moment object.

Similarly inside `interval: function()` get `currentTime` with `var currentTime = moment(moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY ') + time);` only. Now your condition will be like `showTime.some(s => s.startShow <= currentTime && s.endShow >= currentTime)` which will return true if `currentTime` is between any `startShow` & `endShow` from any `showTime` array.

```
var showTime = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jsonStr[4].length; i < i++) {
  showTime.push({
    startShow: moment(jsonStr[4][i].start_show),
    endShow: moment(jsonStr[4][i].end_show),
    title: moment(jsonStr[4][i].title)
  });
}

var theCounters = $('.clock .value').FlipClock({
  clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
  callbacks: {
    interval: function() {
      var time = this.factory.getTime().time;
      var currentTime = moment(moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY ') + time);

      //Here I need the currentTime check if there is a time between startShow and endShow matched.
      // Loop over each show time
      showTime.forEach(s => {
        // Check condition for whether current time falls between any show time
        // and alert status with show title
        if (s.startShow <= currentTime && s.endShow >= currentTime) {
          alert("matched - " + s.title);
        } else {
          alert("not matched - " + s.title);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

---

Try it at below.

```js
var showTime = [];
// adding dateString for testing only. You should use date from your response
var dateString = moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY ');

// add start, end time & title into object to be pushed into array
showTime.push({
  startShow: moment(dateString + '18:32:40'),
  endShow: moment(dateString + '18:53:55'),
  title: "abc"
});
showTime.push({
  startShow: moment(dateString + '17:32:40'),
  endShow: moment(dateString + '18:23:55'),
  title: "def"
});

var time = '18:20:00';
var currentTime = moment(moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY ') + time);

// Loop over each show time
showTime.forEach(s => {
  // Check condition for whether current time falls between any show time
  // and alert status with show title
  if (s.startShow <= currentTime && s.endShow >= currentTime) {
    alert("matched - " + s.title);
  } else {
    alert("not matched - " + s.title);
  }
});

//if (showTime.some(s => s.startShow <= currentTime && s.endShow >= currentTime)) {
//  alert("matched");
//} else {
//  alert("not matched");
//}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-lMkd3Y03vWd6SXDKGLaPgbco+3VNI4xtwiuADZvr29hzHhxIdonDcZQF0k/eAf6/1vI4b2eNqkkIm42Hjxiz6A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It always return me not matched, on my example : if current datetime now: 19:20:00, We still have 2 datetime show, 01/12/2021 19:32:40,01/12/2021 19:50:40

Comment: I have updated `currentTime` object to get with date also. and updated condition inside `if`. Created snippet so you can now test as well.

Comment: Hi, I tried your update code and working. But why it is only alert me 1 time? As we know it should alert 2 times right? And how to get the value if inside each `showTime.push` have ex: `title: "abc"` and `title: "def"`

Comment: Though `showTime` has two values but `showTime.some(...)` will return `true` if at least one of the condition is matching. Also we have used `if` just once & It is not inside loop so alert is showing just once.

Comment: Is it possible to make it with loop? and any clue regarding my previous question about `abc` and `def`?

Comment: Updated code with `forEach` loop. You can also use `for` loop. Also added `title` property into `showTime` array.

Comment: Awesome, sorry for late respond. It's working perfect. Thanks for your time (y)

Comment: Hi Karan, I have another question related with this, if you have time, please check it out on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915214/javascript-jquery-to-show-hide-data-in-loop-based-on-schedule-time-to-show-hide