# Javascript/jQuery to show/hide data in loop based on schedule time to show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I'm working with FlipClock js.

```
var showTime = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jsonStr[4].length; i < i++)
{
    showTime.push({
        startShow: moment(jsonStr[4][i].start_show).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
        endShow: moment(jsonStr[4][i].end_show).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
        newstickerData: jsonStr[4][i].news,
        newstickerID: jsonStr[4][i].id
    });
}

var theCounters = $('.clock .value').FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
    callbacks:
    {
        interval:function()
        {
            var time = this.factory.getTime().time;
            var currentTime2 = (moment(time).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));

            showTime.forEach(s =>
            {
                if(s.startShow <= currentTime2 && s.endShow >= currentTime2)
                {
                    field.push({
                        newstickerID: s.newstickerID,
                        newstickerData: s.newstickerData
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

for(var i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
{
    $('.announcement .announcementBox ul').append("<li id='" + field[i].newstickerID + "'>" + field[i].newstickerData + "</li>");
}
```

Now I have data in table like this:

```
id | news | start_show          | end_show
1  | abc  | 2021-01-12 18:32:40 | 2021-01-13 18:53:55
2  | def  | 2021-01-12 17:32:40 | 2021-01-12 18:23:40
3  | ghi  | 2021-01-27 15:01:10 | 2021-01-30 19:32:40
4  | jkl  | 2021-01-12 18:10:40 | 2021-01-30 19:50:40
```

Now I have function to hide/show news based on `start_show` and `end_show`. Assume current date time is `2021-01-27 15:00:00` and as you can see above data, id no `1` and `2` will not show cause We have this condition `if(s.startShow <= currentTime2 && s.endShow >= currentTime2)`. Until this part, it's working good.

ID no `4` will show.

Now the problem is ID no `3` with `start_show` `2021-01-27 15:01:10`, as We know the current date time is `2021-01-27 15:00:00`. But after the flipclock time `currentTime2` meet the condition, ID no `3` never show.

And another problem is, when `end_show` is meet the condition to hide, it's not hide.

My question is, how to make it show/hide as per schedule with my above function?

Note: when I tried to alert inside `showTime.forEach(s =>` with `alert(s.newstickerData)`, (start_show meet the condition) I can see the data ID No `3`. But it's not fire into `$('.announcement .announcementBox ul')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `append` logic inside `callback`. Check comments in explanation.

```js
var showTime = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jsonStr[4].length; i < i++) {
  showTime.push({
    startShow: moment(jsonStr[4][i].start_show).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
    endShow: moment(jsonStr[4][i].end_show).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
    newstickerData: jsonStr[4][i].news,
    newstickerID: jsonStr[4][i].id
  });
}

var theCounters = $('.clock .value').FlipClock({
  clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
  callbacks: {
    interval: function() {
      var time = this.factory.getTime().time;
      var currentTime2 = (moment(time).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));

      // get ul object into which we need to append li
      let ul = $('.announcement .announcementBox ul');
      // find all existing li inside ul & remove
      ul.find('li').remove();
      // take variable for index
      let i = 0;

      showTime.forEach(s => {
        if (s.startShow <= currentTime2 && s.endShow >= currentTime2) {
          // append li into ul
          ul.append("<li id='" + s.newstickerID + "'>" + s.newstickerData + "</li>");
          // increment index
          i++;
          // remove below code is field array is not needed.
          field.push({
            newstickerID: s.newstickerID,
            newstickerData: s.newstickerData
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

// move below loop inside callbacks
//for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
//  $('.announcement .announcementBox ul').append("<li id='" + field[i].newstickerID + "'>" + field[i].newstickerData + "</li>");
//}
```

Comment: Hi @Karan, it is show me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'newstickerID' of undefined`

Comment: Need to use `s.newstickerID` instead of `field[i].newstickerID` & `s.newstickerData` instead of `field[i].newstickerData` with `ul.append(...)`. Updated my answer. Please try now.

Comment: I forgot to inform that I use jQuery newsticker effect also. That's why I put `$('.announcement .announcementBox ul')` outside the loop. Tried your code but the data change together every second. Is there any way to keep the data show with newsticker effect one by one?